# Why is the gain in a cascode current mirror controlled by M1 and M2 instead of M3 and M4?

Tags: mosfet, analog, design

I know from simulations, books, and teachers that the gain (Iout/Iin) of a cascode current mirror (shown in the picture below) is controlled by relation (W/L)_2 / (W/L)_1 instead of (W/L)_4 / (W/L)_3 as in a simple current mirror. I can't find the reason why this happens using the formulas for saturation region.

[image]

Comment: M3, M4 gates are floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'll assume that the gates of M3 and M4 are biased rather than floating, and that all four transistors are indeed in saturation.

**tl;dr** The width of M3 and M4 has a very indirect, weak effect on the drain current ratio (square root, times a small factor for channel length modulation). The width of M1 and M2 directly controls the drain current ratio.

**qualitatively:** Starting with the intent of the cascode - The upper (cascode) transistors operate in an arrangement resembling [common gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_gate) - the gate is held at a constant voltage, while the transistor acts as a current buffer. This current-buffering behavior is key to the operation of a cascode - the upper transistors, acting as current buffers, withstand swings in drain voltage while keeping their source voltages nearly constant.

In turn, this nearly-constant source voltage on M3/M4 is a nearly-constant drain voltage on M1/M2 - M1 and M2 are "protected" from drain voltage swings, while they control the drain current.

**quantitatively:** Consider the equation for drain current under saturation, \$I_D=\frac{1}{2}\mu_nC_{ox}\frac{W}{L}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})^2(1 + \lambda V_{DS})\$. M1/M2 Vds is kept nearly constant by M3 and M4, so the transistors operate closer to ideal square-law behavior. Since M1 and M2 have the same Vgs, the current in the left and right branches is set by the ratio of their widths.

On the other hand, the widths of M3 and M4 have a much more indirect effect on the current ratio:

- If M3 and M4 have mismatched widths, then that mismatch leads to a smaller mismatch in Vgs (drain current follows square of overdrive voltage, so overdrive voltage follows square root of drain current)
- That mismatch in Vgs shows up on the *drain* of M1 and M2. While M1 and M2 might be affected by channel-length modulation, that control is still very weak (a factor of \$1 + \lambda V_{DS}\$). Vgs (which is constant because M1 and M2 share gate and source nets) has much more control over the drain current in each FET.